# why skip character needed for each character read

Tags: c

```
scanf("%c",&a);

printf("enter a character NUMBER\n");

scanf(" %c",&b);

printf("enter a character NUMBER\n");

scanf(" %c",&c);
```

In the above code, why i have to include skip character before reading another character?

Comment: The space character in format string "consumes" any number of whitespace characters in the input, including newline characters - which are inevitable when you press enter after your inputs.

Comment: Because you decided to work with input that contain newline characters that should be skipped?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when by the question. What is a "skip character" and where are you "including" it?

Comment: Why?  Slightly sarcastic answer: because `scanf` sucks.  If you must use `scanf`, follow these rules: (1) Only use `%d`, `%f`, and `%s`, never `%c` (or `%[...]`). (2) Never intermix calls to `scanf` with calls to `fgets` (or `gets`). (3) Don't try to read more than one value with one `scanf` call (that is, limit yourself to one `%` per format statement). (4) Always check the return value to see if it's 1. (5) Remember to use `&`, except with `%s`. (6) If you're trying to do something more complicated, that you can't do within these rules, it's time to abandon `scanf`, and use something better.

Comment: Serious answer: You almost always want to use a space before `%c`, because there's almost always some whitespace to skip -- perhaps the newline that was leftover from the previous response the user typed.  That's why the other format specifiers (`%d`, `%f`, etc.) always *do* skip leading whitespace, and why its so confusing that `%c` doesn't by default.

Comment: And if using `%s`, make sure to limit the maximum length of the string, and not use a bare `%s` format.

Comment: Although I whole-heartedly agree with @SteveSummit that scanf should be avoided ("sucks" is an understatement!), I think `%[...]` is a better choice that `%s` in many situations.  If you use either, you *must* always include a width modifier to avoid an overflow.  Either `%s` or `%[` without a width modifier is no better than `gets`

Comment: @WilliamPursell My personal opinion (you don't have to agree with me) is that there's no use for `%[...]`.  It's like a turbocharger on a tricycle.  `%s` is fine for toy programs -- the only programs that typically use (or that should us) `scanf` in the first place.  If you need `%[...]`, I believe that's proof you're doing something sophisticated enough that you should move beyond `scanf`.

Comment: I'm not adamant about length modifiers with `%s` (and `%[...]`), either.  Yes, preventing buffer overflows is vitally important.  But so is preventing crashes.  You would probably agree with the rule, "You would never go out on the road on a vehicle without brakes."  And yet, tricycles don't have brakes.  So I'm actually fine if a `scanf`-using program has a potential buffer overflow vulnerability, because any `scanf`-using program is a toy, that will never be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

because when you type enter after entering the first character.the new line character `\n` get stuck in the buffer.so you need to include this skip character or you can use after every `scanf()` a `getchar()` function without arguments.